# My Calendar won't display data. How can I map data into the root of a component in TOAST UI Calendar?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-effect, array.prototype.map, tui-calendar

My TUI Calendar won't display data. How can I map data from the server into the root of a component. Currently nothing seem to be appearing, except it renders the calendar twice.

```
const MembersCalendar = () => {
const [event, setEvent] = useState<any[]>([]);

useEffect(() => {
   get (`${remoteRoutes.events}`, (data) => { 
      console.log(data);
      setEvent(data);
   },
)},[]);
    
return (
    <Layout>
        <h1>Calendar</h1>
        {event.map((mcEvent, index) => {
            return (
                //This seems to be where the problem is. TUI does not display events. 
                <TUICalendar 
                    key={index} 
                    height="1000px" 
                    view="month" 
                    calendars={calendars}
                    schedules={mcEvent} 
                />
            );
        })}
    </Layout>
)
```

Comment: Why are you displaying one calendar for each event? Maybe, you need to have just one TUICalendar. And pass events to schedules as an array.

Comment: Thanks for that tip, I passed the data into the ISchedule, and finally got it to work